# Visual Studio Code Powershell extension does not recognize profile while debugging

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I’m using the [Powershell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).  I updated the profile:

> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1

To include some functions and variables that I want to make available to other scripts.  When I reference a variable from the profile within another script, it does not appear that the profile has been loaded.  I suspect this because the variable value is blank when I query it from the VS Code console.  If I run the same test from the standard Powershell console with an associated profile, the variable value is resolved.

Can anyone tell me what, if anything, I need to do to use a Powershell profile in VS Code while debugging?

Answer (score 7):

There are several profiles. The starting point is the four locations that you can find by reading the following properties of PowerShell's built-in `$profile` variable.

```
$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
$profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
$profile.AllUsersAllHosts
```

As noted in [this article by The Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/), because Windows has both Powershell and the Powershell ISE, you have at least two possible values of Current Host, so at least 6 profiles.

I've tested this in the Visual Studio Code terminal window, and it seems that the "CurrentHost" profiles are the same as you get by simply running a powershell instance. I'd assume then that Code isn't seen as a distinct host, and just runs a normal powershell. 
Once you've got that far, there's another possible complication, which is that the `AllUsers` profiles are down in `C:\Windows\System32` and hence on a 64 bit system, also mirrored in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`. So depending on whether you are using a 32 or 64 bit editor, and whether the Powershell is hosted in a 32 or 64 bit process, it is quite possible that the file you are editing has no influence on the Powershell.

Answer (score 5):

Inside your debug session run: `$profile`. This will return the path to currently used profile file, so you can make your changes there.

Alternatively you could change the system wide profile in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`

Comment: As I indicated, I made the changes in the appropriate profile.  I'd rather not change a system wide profile.

Comment: If `$profile` returning path `C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1`, then raise a bug with VS Code team :)

Comment: @Raf .. or just dot source the "correct" $profile in the VSCode $profile: . .\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Comment: Regarding the system-wide $profile, I thought that it is sourced by default when you source the more special ones. But no, you have to source it manually.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tik9/prs/blob/master/Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1) is an example of dotting the PS profile in the VSCode profile. Either way is possible, I decided to change and extend the PS file.

Answer (score 3):

If you type $profile in the "PowerShell Integrated Console" of VSCode, you will see the path to the profile used:
`C:\Users\xxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1`

Now if you type $profile in a normal terminal, you will see your "normal" profile: `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Now the easiest solution that did the trick for me is to create a hard link between the two files (the VSCode_profile.ps1 file didn't exist in my case):
`mklink /H Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1 Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Reload VSCode and you are all set!

Comment: No, you will not see the VSCode_profile, otherwise it is a bug, according to RAF's answer..

Answer (score 2):

With the just [released version 0.10.0](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/releases/tag/v0.10.0) of the VS Code PowerShell extension debugging with a previously loaded profile.ps1 being available is now implemented. Note that the interactive console and the debugger share the same PS session.